# Reading a single char in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

I want to read a single character from the keyboard (like BASIC GET, FORTH KEY or C getchar. It looks as if to do this with python I have to load a package and extract a module from this. Surely there is an easier way? Can't I just read stdin?

Comment: take a look at [getch()](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/)

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203067/listening-to-keyboard-events-without-trapping-them][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203067/listening-to-keyboard-events-without-trapping-them